# Find the set of points twice as far away from one point than another

Tags: algebra-precalculus, locus

> Find the equation of the locus of points that are twice as far from the point $(2, 0)$ as they are from $(5, 0)$.

So from my understanding its the set of all $(x,y)$ such that

$$2\sqrt{(x-2)^2+y^2}=\sqrt{(x-5)^2+y^2}$$

But (solving for $y$) this is not the correct answer.

Comment: This is an [Apollonian circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circles_of_Apollonius).

Comment: Did I set it up correctly? @TobyMak

Comment: @HossienSahebjame The factor $2$ is multiplying the wrong distance.

Comment: So its $\sqrt{(x-2)^2+y^2}=2\sqrt{(x-5)^2+y^2}$??

Comment: @HossienSahebjame Yes, the distance to $(2,0)$ is twice the distance to $(5,0)$

Comment: Yes. If 6 is twice as much as 3, then $2 \cdot 6 \ne 3$ but $6 = 2 \cdot 3$.

Comment: oh my gosh cannot believe the wording got me there! thanks!!